# developing functions that tests whether the proposed solution is a solution?

Tags: scheme, racket

For example, the quadratic equation `x^2 + 2x + 1 = 0` is a claim concerning some unknown number `x`.

So if you substitute the `x = -1`, the claim holds since it would equal `0`. 
But if you substitute `x = 1`, the claim won't be true because you would get `4`.

Now I've been told to develop a function that tests whether a few problems are in fact a solution.

Where would I start for this one below?

```
10x – 6 = 7x + 9
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Are you asking "how do I find the solutions to a linear equation?"

Comment: Or are you asking how to solve it e.g. 5

Comment: Trying to develop functions that test whether the proposed solution is, in fact, a solution for 10x-6= 7x +9. I am told to test this function with numbers that are solutions and numbers that arent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the chosen representation for functions. If you pass them as lambdas, it's trivial to test if a "claim" is true or false:

```
(define (test-claim f1 f2 x)
  (= (f1 x) (f2 x)))

For example:

; x^2 + 2x + 1 = 0, x = -1    
(test-claim (lambda (x) (+ (* x x) (* 2 x) 1))
            (lambda (x) 0)
            -1)

=> #t

; x^2 + 2x + 1 = 0, x = 1    
(test-claim (lambda (x) (+ (* x x) (* 2 x) 1))
            (lambda (x) 0)
            1)

=> #f

; 10x – 6 = 7x + 9, x = 5    
(test-claim (lambda (x) (- (* 10 x) 6))
            (lambda (x) (+ (* 7 x) 9))
            5)

=> #t

; 10x – 6 = 7x + 9, x = 10    
(test-claim (lambda (x) (- (* 10 x) 6))
            (lambda (x) (+ (* 7 x) 9))
            10)

=> #f
```